# wso2 carbon and devolper Studio - Message Stores/Processors

Tags: wso2

Is there any way to create Message Stores/Processors in the Carbon or Developer Studio?

I need to create them, add them to the CAR and deploy in the WSO2 ESB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Developer Studio does not support creation of Message Stores and Message Processors at the moment.

It is in our Road Map and we will include it in a future release.

Harshana

Answer (score 0):

Developer Studio 3.2.0 version supports creation of Message Stores and Message Processors and they can be added to a CAR and deploy in the WSO2 ESB.

You can download Developer Studio 3.2.0 version from [here](http://dist.wso2.org/products/developer-studio/3.2.0/wso2-developer-studio-3.2.0.zip).

Regards,
Asanka Sanjeewa.